# Copying Excel sheets from a another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I try to copy sheets from another workbook, but the problem that I want to **start copying sheets from a certain sheet that I know the name**.

I tried to adapt several codes that copy all sheets but I cannot.

Here is a example of my code:

```
Sub CreationDeBaseDeDonneesAvril2018()

Worksheets.Add After:=ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Dim Counter As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim FirstMonth As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook


Set wb = Workbooks.Open(")

For Each ws In wb                          
If ws.Name = "01m" Then
Exit For                          
End If
Next
ws.Activate
Counter = activeworksheet.Count

For i = Counter To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

Worksheets(i).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Next
End Sub
```

Thanks you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

*This VBA (Macro) code will help you to Copy certain Sheets from closed Workbook to current Workbook.*

```
Sub CopyFromClosedWBK()

Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet

Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\FolderName\WhicheverFile.xlsm")
wbSource.Sheets("Sheet2").Copy After:=wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet4")
wbSource.Close
End Sub
```

**N.B**

- File Path with Source book as well as Folder 
  and Sheet Name's are  editable.
- You may add as many sheets to Copy using,
  `wbSource.Sheets("Sheet2").Copy After:=` 
  command line.